# Реализация фотогалереи

Tags: html, javascript

[Галерея лота на 40 фоток](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EMr5qVLEQM&feature=player_embedded).
Нужно что-то подобное, как на этом видео, только на меленькое количество фото, не более 10. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

[HighSlide главная](http://highslide.com/)

[HighSlide редактор](http://highslide.com/editor/)

Выбирайте, настраивайте, очень всё подробно и доступно описано.